# Oracle Data Integrator (ODI) can't find Create new Data Store option

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I'am trying to create mapping between my source tables and target tables ,i want to create a custom data store for my destination model but when i do right click on the destination model i can't find (create new datastore) option in the list! can someone please tell me what causing this?

Regards

Comment: can you provide a picture of your console ?  It should be on the Models tree in Designer Navigator, select a Model or a Sub-Model and right click  select new data store

Comment: dear that option was not found, after a lot of thinking I found that the user that accesses the repository doesn't have access to WRITE ,